# Sort XML feed using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Below is my XML feed

```
<atom:feed xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wplc="http://www.ibm.com/wplc/atom/1.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<atom:entry>
    <atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id>
    <atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title>
    <wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="priority">2.0</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field>
</atom:entry>
<atom:entry>
    <atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id>
    <atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title>
    <wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="priority">1.0</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field>
</atom:entry>
<atom:entry>
    <atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id>
    <atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title>
    <wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="priority">3.0</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field>
</atom:entry>
<atom:entry>
    <atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id>
    <atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title>
    <wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="priority">1.0</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field>
</atom:entry>
</atom:feed>
```

Here I am trying to sort the result where wplc:field id="priority" = 1.0 or 2.0
I mean there will be alot of atom:entry tags in my ajax call resulted XML, from that feed I want to sort the results based on the priority attribute.

I need to display only results where priority is 1.0 and 2.0 that too in ascending order.

I am using JQuery like

```
$(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function(){
   $(this).find('wplc\\:field, field').each(function(){
       //Here I need to sort the results
   });
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:display you can arrange by your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var xml='<atom:feed xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:wplc="http://www.ibm.com/wplc/atom/1.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><atom:entry><atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id><atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title><wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>';
 xml=xml+' <wplc:field id="priority">2.0</wplc:field><wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field><wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field><wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field></atom:entry><atom:entry><atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id><atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title><wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>';
 xml=xml+'  <wplc:field id="priority">1.0</wplc:field><wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field><wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field><wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field></atom:entry><atom:entry><atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id><atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title><wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>';
 xml=xml+' <wplc:field id="priority">3.0</wplc:field><wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field><wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field><wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field></atom:entry><atom:entry><atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id><atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title><wplc:field id="update_date">1435143446000</wplc:field>';
 xml=xml+'<wplc:field id="priority">1.0</wplc:field><wplc:field id="summary">summary.</wplc:field><wplc:field id="acls">public</wplc:field><wplc:field id="phone">214-456-2240</wplc:field></atom:entry></atom:feed>';
var docs=[],x=0;
var docs1=[],x1=0;
   xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
   $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
   $($xml).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function(){
    var dataset=$(this)[0].innerHTML;
    console.log($(this));
     $(this).find('wplc\\:field, field').each(function(){
         console.log(this.id);
         if(this.id=='priority'){
          if(this.innerHTML=="1.0"){
                   docs[x]=dataset;
                   x++;
          }else if(this.innerHTML=="2.0"){
           docs1[x1]=dataset;
           x1++;
          }
                 
         }
     });
  });
   docs= docs.concat(docs1);
console.log(docs);
$str=docs.join("<br>");
$("#result").html($str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result"></p>
```